# Error converting data type varchar to decimal, --data type errors

Tags: sql, casting, type-conversion, ssms-2012

I am altering a view to cast geographic coordinates (numbers with varying decimal precision) into a decimal field.

I have confirmed that the only items in the source tables are numbers and decimals -- but I am getting the error

> "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Is it possible the decimal in the source table is being read as a character, and if so, what could I do to successfully execute this conversion?

```
ALTER VIEW [SCHEMA].[VIEW_V]
AS SELECT   
        cast(field 1 AS decimal (26,19)) as x_coord         
   FROM   [linkedServer].[Sourcedatabase].[schema].[dt_table]
```

Comment: You may think that all the values are numbers, but SQL Server knows better.  You could have a variety of problems, most likely, non-numeric characters in the field.  You could have different internationalization settings on the two machines, so commas or periods get rejected.  I think this is a data problem, not a SQL problem.

Answer (score 4):

Trying using `isnumeric()` or `try_convert()`:

```
ALTER VIEW [SCHEMA].[VIEW_V] AS
    SELECT (CASE WHEN isnumeric(field1) = 1 
                 THEN cast(field1 AS decimal(26,19)) 
            END)as x_coord
    FROM   [linkedServer].[Sourcedatabase].[schema].[dt_table];
```

or

```
ALTER VIEW [SCHEMA].[VIEW_V] AS
    SELECT try_convert(decimal(26, 19), field1) 
    FROM   [linkedServer].[Sourcedatabase].[schema].[dt_table];
```

Where the resulting value is `NULL`, you will know which rows are causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

In case of float values with characters 'e' '+' it errors out if we try to convert in decimal. ('2.81104e+006'). It still pass ISNUMERIC test.

SELECT ISNUMERIC('2.81104e+006') returns 1.

SELECT convert(decimal(15,2), '2.81104e+006') returns error: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

SELECT try_convert(decimal(15,2), '2.81104e+006') returns NULL.

SELECT convert(float, '2.81104e+006') it returns correct value 2811040.